# REST Api returns empty items

Tags: rest-api

I've been working on a new Magento implementation for a client, and I seem to be hitting a snag with the Magento REST API. I had no issues getting past Oauth. I've run into that before, but my question is about how Magento stores information.

When I make a request like http://www.myMagentoHost.com/api/rest/products?limit=25

The returned JSON contains results with just a string for each entry from 1 to 25. I'll provide an example below. The product catalog in our site has a large amount of product information in it. So I'm not sure why none of that information is being returned. This request is made as a guest user as I'm trying to expose this information to general browsing via a 3rd party mobile application.

I'm a newbie to Magento, so I was wondering if I need to change any settings to expose the pricing and product information to the REST api, or if I'm simply doing something wrong.

{

```
    "1": [],
    "4": [],
    "5": [],
    "6": [],
    "7": [],
    "8": [],
    "9": [],
    "10": [],
    "11": [],
    "12": [],
    "13": [],
    "14": [],
    "15": [],
    "16": [],
    "17": [],
    "18": [],
    "19": [],
    "20": [],
    "21": [],
    "22": [],
    "23": [],
    "24": [],
    "25": []
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm silly. I wasn't doing anything wrong in my code/OAuth Process. I just checked the wrong box in the Roles settings. The user that the app uses to interact with the site was given a role with no read permissions. That should have been the first thing that I checked.

Whoops!